# make_heap() function parameters - what if i don't want to include certain elements?

Tags: c++, stl

Question about `make_heap` function.
When making a heap in `stl` using `make_heap`
it takes `v.begin()` and `v.end()` // `[front, end)`
but what if I don't want to add 10 in to the heap..

I thought I could accomplish this by using:

```
make_heap(v.begin(),v.end()-1);
```

But this isn't giving me any different output.. I tried using  `make_heap(v.begin(),v.end()-1);` instead of `make_heap(v.begin(),v.end());`
But output is the same...

What's happening here?..

Code #1:

```
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>     


int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+10);




  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
  std::cout << "range :";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << v[i];

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Code #2:

```
#include <algorithm>   
#include <vector>      

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+10);




  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end()-1);

  std::cout << "range :";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << v[i];

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Both giving me same output.. (?)

Comment: Compiler? version? The g++4.8.2 at coliru gives a different output for those two programs. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0228874747550608)

Comment: Oh i think i got it.. its still printing out all 10 elements because I'm using v.size() and v[i] to print elements..so basically make_heap() simply orders the elements in the vector v.. not create a new vector itself.. correct?...

Comment: It still shouldn't give you the *same* output. The second program shouldn't move the element `10`, so it should stay at the end. The first program is required to put that element at the front.

Comment: yes you are correct. what i meant by the same output was that it still gave me total of 10 data when i was only expecting 9.. but i think i understand why my thinking was wrong..  its because make_heap(), isn't actually creating a whole new vector right?.. but just simply ordering the data inside vector v..

Comment: The Standard Library algorithms are all decoupled from the containers via iterators. They don't operate on the containers at all, but only on those iterators / single elements. Consequently, they don't create new containers. They either operate in-place or use an output range (like [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform))

Comment: In any question where you say something about not getting expected output, you should post the output you're seeing and point out specifically where it's not meeting your expectations.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry . yes i should've been more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer per say, but I was unable to reproduce your results: I obtain two different outputs.

Program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void code1() 
{
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+10);

  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
  std::cout << "range :";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << v[i];

  std::cout << '\n';
}

void code2() 
{
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+10);

  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end()-1);
  std::cout << "range :";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << v[i];

  std::cout << '\n';
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    code1();
    code2();
}
```

Compilation & Output:

```
john@---:/tmp$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

john@---:/tmp$ g++ -o so2 so2.cpp
john@---:/tmp$ ./so2
range : 10 9 7 8 5 6 3 1 4 2
range : 9 8 7 4 5 6 3 2 1 10
john@---:/tmp$
```